# What is this type of function call with 2 pairs of brackets `BatchNormalization(axis = 3)(X, training = training)` in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I was going through some python code today, I saw some weird syntax of calling function with 2 sets of parameters `BatchNormalization(axis = 3)(X, training = training)`
Can any say what is it called in python so that I can go through this concept : ) ....

Comment: I think this syntax is referred to as [chaining layer transformations](https://keras.io/getting_started/intro_to_keras_for_engineers/#building-models-with-the-keras-functional-api). I've seen it in Keras commonly.

Comment: The first callable (a function or class, as in your case) returns another callable which is then called with the the second set of parameters.